# Power BI bottom page navigation pane color change

Tags: web, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

how to change color of bottom page pane´s color in power BI? the problem is i need to publish the file in website and need to change the bottom pane color according to website theme. The pciture is attached where the color needs to be changed[image]

no help yet, i treid to work through many solutions but no help.

Comment: What screen is this in power bi? This does not look like the standard navigation in a report

Comment: You can't if it is publish to web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI Report Server supports [Branding the web portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal).

A brand package for Reporting Services consists of three items and is packaged as a zip file:

1. metadata.xml
2. colors.json
3. logo.png (optional)

To update the colors, you need to create a color.json file
which will look something like:

```
    {  
"name":"Multicolored example brand",  
"version":"1.0",  
"interface":{  
    "primary":"#b31e1e",  
    "primaryAlt":"#ca0806",  
    "primaryAlt2":"#621013",  
    "primaryAlt3":"#e40000",  
    "primaryAlt4":"#e14e50",  
    "primaryContrast":"#fff",  

    "secondary":"#042200",  
    "secondaryAlt":"#0f4400",  
    "secondaryAlt2":"#155500",  
    "secondaryAlt3":"#217700",  
    "secondaryContrast":"#49e63c",  

    "neutralPrimary":"#d8edff",  
    "neutralPrimaryAlt":"#c9e6ff",  
    "neutralPrimaryAlt2":"#aedaff",  
    "neutralPrimaryAlt3":"#88c8ff",  
    "neutralPrimaryContrast":"#0a2b4c",  

    "neutralSecondary":"#e9d8eb",  
    "neutralSecondaryAlt":"#d9badc",  
    "neutralSecondaryAlt2":"#b06cb5",  
    "neutralSecondaryAlt3":"#a75bac",  
    "neutralSecondaryContrast":"#250a26",  

    "neutralTertiary":"#f79220",  
    "neutralTertiaryAlt":"#f8a54b",  
    "neutralTertiaryAlt2":"#facc9b",  
    "neutralTertiaryAlt3":"#fce3c7",  
    "neutralTertiaryContrast":"#391d00",  

    "danger":"#ff0000",  
    "success":"#00ff00",  
    "warning":"#ff8800",  
    "info":"#00ff",  
    "dangerContrast":"#fff",  
    "successContrast":"#fff",  
    "warningContrast":"#fff",  
    "infoContrast":"#fff",  


    
    "itemTypeIconColor":"#ffffff",
    "reportIconBackground":"#12239e",
    "excelIconBackground":"#217346",
    "folderIconBackground":"#4668c5",
    "datasetIconBackground":"#c94f0f",
    "otherIconBackground":"#000000"        
    },  
    "theme":{  
    "dataPoints":[  
        "#0072c6",  
        "#f68c1f",  
        "#269657",  
        "#dd5900",  
        "#5b3573",  
        "#22bdef",  
        "#b4009e",  
        "#008274",  
        "#fdc336",  
        "#ea3c00",  
        "#00188f",  
        "#9f9f9f"  
    ],  

    "good":"#85ba00",  
    "bad":"#e90000",  
    "neutral":"#edb327",  
    "none":"#333",  

    "background":"#fff",  
    "foreground":"#222",  
    "mapBase":"#00aeef",  
    "panelBackground":"#f6f6f6",  
    "panelForeground":"#222",  
    "panelAccent":"#00aeef",  
    "tableAccent":"#00aeef",  

    "altBackground":"#f6f6f6",  
    "altForeground":"#000",  
    "altMapBase":"#f68c1f",  
    "altPanelBackground":"#235378",  
    "altPanelForeground":"#fff",  
    "altPanelAccent":"#fdc336",  
    "altTableAccent":"#fdc336"  
}  
}
```

Then add the color.json in metadata.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<SystemResourcePackage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/systemresourcepackagemetadata"  
    type="UniversalBrand"  
    version="2.0.2"  
    name="Multicolored example brand"  
    >  
    <Contents>  
        <Item key="colors" path="colors.json" />  
        <Item key="logo" path="logo.png" />  
    </Contents>  
</SystemResourcePackage>
```

Package these files into a zip file, and upload it into the web portal by following the [steps mentioned in the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal?view=sql-server-ver16#applying-the-brand-package-to-the-web-portal)

**Reference:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal
2. https://youtu.be/m08kLuofwFA

Comment: is there any other possible way to do it without branding via sql query?